# rails check if a form was completely filled out

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have information in my rails view that I only want to show up if the user has entered all personal details in the database, such as name, firstname, street and city. I could now do this:

```
if user.name && user.firstname && user.street && user.street
# show stuff
end
```

but I don't think that is very elegant and "the rails way". Is there an easier and smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `required` in your html form tags and validations in Model Class. Also follow links: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

In your model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def has_required_fields?
    self.name && self.first_name && self.address && ....
  end
end
```

And in your controller

```
 if user.has_required_fields?
   # do whatever you want
 end
```

Comment: No that is not what I want to do. I want to filter information independently from the form.

Answer (score 0):

The "rails way" would be thin controller, fat model. So, in your case, you'd want to create a method inside your `User` model and use it in your controller afterwards.

**User model**:

```
def incomplete?
  name.blank? or firstname.blank? or street.blank?
end
```

**User controller**:

```
unless user.incomplete?
  # Show stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in model:

```
ALL_REQUIRED_FIELDS = %w(name surname address email)

def filled_required_fields?
  ALL_REQUIRED_FIELDS.all? { |field| self.attribute_present? field }
end
```

in your controller:

```
@user.filled_required_fields?
```

will return true if all fields filled and false if not.

**looks very gracefully :)**